# Imprimir tres en raya

Tags: java

```
public class TresEnRaya {
    private char[]tablero;
    private int partidas;
    private char turno;
    private boolean ganador;

    public TresEnRaya() {
        this.tablero = new char[9];
        this.partidas = 9;
        this.turno = 'X';
        this.ganador = false;
    }

    public void getTablero(){
       System.out.printnln("----------------------------------");
       System.out.printnln(tablero[0] + " | " + tablero[1] + " | " + tablero[2]);
       System.out.printnln(tablero[3] + " | " + tablero[4] + " | " + tablero[5]);
       System.out.printnln(tablero[6] + " | " + tablero[7] + " | " + tablero[8]);
       System.out.printnln("----------------------------------");
    }

    
    private boolean checkPos(int pos){
        boolean ocupado = false;
        if(pos<0 || pos>=9)
            ocupado = true;
        else if(tablero[pos]=='X' || tablero[pos]=='0')
            ocupado = true;
        return ocupado;
    }
    
    public boolean checkGanador(){
        if(tablero[0]==turno && tablero[1]==turno && tablero[2]==turno)
            ganador = true;
        if(tablero[3]==turno && tablero[4]==turno && tablero[5]==turno)
            ganador = true;
        if(tablero[6]==turno && tablero[7]==turno && tablero[8]==turno)
            ganador = true;
        if(tablero[0]==turno && tablero[4]==turno && tablero[8]==turno)
            ganador = true;
        if(tablero[2]==turno && tablero[4]==turno && tablero[6]==turno)
            ganador = true;
        
        return ganador;
    }
    

    public void juega(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pos;

        do{
            do{
                System.out.println("Introduce la posicion de " + turno);
                pos = sc.nextInt()-1;
            }while(checkPos(pos));
            
            tablero[pos] = turno;
            
            getTablero();
            checkGanador();
            
            if(ganador)
                break;
            else if(turno == 'X')
                turno = '0';
            else
                turno = 'X';
            partidas--;
            
        }while(partidas>0 && !ganador);
        
        if(ganador)
            System.out.println("El ganador es " + turno);
        else
            System.out.println("Empate");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TresEnRaya partida = new TresEnRaya();
        partida.juega();
    }
```

}

Buenas, no sé como imprimir bien el tablero. Ya que cada vez que ingreso una posición con el turno que sea se me desplaza el tablero y queda horrible, si alguien sabe hacer esto y me explica como lo ha hecho. (Por ejemplo usando String.format, si alguien lo resuelve y me lo explica le estaré muy agradecido)

PD: He tenido que cambiar el código que tenía antes para que me acepten la pregunta, no sé cual es el problema del rechazo, ya que le pregunta está clara y la repito por si acaso: Necesito imprimir correctamente el tablero de este tres en raya y que no sé desplace cada vez que introduzco la posición de mi turno, y que me expliquen como lo han hecho, gracias.

Comment: Esa es la gracia de chatGPT: no necesitas entender, aprender ni saber. Siempre lo tendrás a mano para resolver cualquier tarea o trabajo.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask]. Aquí no se dan orientaciones, ni tutoriales, ni se proveen librerías ni recursos externos. [es.so] _no es un foro de discusión_ (tal como menciona el [tour]). Céntrate en un problema _específico_. De hecho, si el código lo obtuviste de ChatGPT, le hubieras preguntado cómo funciona...

Comment: Hola Jorge, tal vez, (si ejecutas los ejemplos) te sirva este [página](https://codigofacilito.com/articulos/format-string-java).

Comment: No entiendo cual es la pregunta

Comment: la pregunta es que no sé como imprimir ese tres en raya y la impresión que he puesto ahí está sacada de chatGPT porque no sabía hacerla y me interesa saber como hacerlo.

Comment: Hola Jorge, para el código que creaste no se "corra", tenes que inicializar tablero con un for, asignandole a todo **' '**, de esa manera tu solución queda bien.

Comment: claro, pero sin inicializarlo, chatGPT:                          public void getTablero(){
        String line = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
            if (tablero[i] == 0) {
                line += " ";
            } else {
                line += tablero[i];
            }
            if (i % 3 == 2) {
                System.out.println(String.format("| %c | %c | %c |", line.charAt(0), line.charAt(1), line.charAt(2)));
                System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
                line = "";
            }
        }
    }

Comment: esa fue la solución de GPT con mi código actual, por eso digo que no hace falta inicializarlo como dices.

Comment: @Jorge, tal vez me equivoqué, como cambiaste el método **getTablero**, pensé que el nuevo (el que está ahora), era de tu propia cosecha, ese, imprime el tablero pero "corrido", si antes de ejecutarlo, aplicas mi propuesta, imprime bien, la respuesta del "bicho", es buena, y usa otro enfoque.

Comment: PD: cuando escribes un comentario para alguien, recuerda agregar "@nombreUsuario", para que reciba una notificación.